# Slow Appengine build with Maven and Modules

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, module, gae-module

I just converted my GAE application to using modules and started using maven as well. I used the standard appengine archetype to create the project structure.

However, when I run `mvn install` this takes over a minute to build my project. Most of the time is taken building `.war` and `.ear` files. Are these needed for appengine builds?

If not, how do I get these `.war` and `.ear` files to not be packaged for appengine projects?

Answer (score 0):

You should stop in the default life cycle of Maven somewhere before package, say test.

mvn test

Any point at or after package will lead to building a package.

b.t.w. I'm learning how to build an App Engine app with modules. May I ask which archetype did you use? It looks to me this doesn't create a multi-module layout, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#creating_app_engine_applications_or_backend_apis_using_the_archetypes

Another question is how to launch the devserver for modules like the example shown here, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#an_example

Thanks!

Comment: The life cycle of maven is here, http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

Comment: How to launch the devserver for modules, https://plus.google.com/116155312904314109883/posts/TXx7tr9Efoy